# Non-free rings of integers

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, free-modules

Let $L/K$ be a field extension of number fields such that the class number of $K$ is greater one (i.e. $\mathcal O_K$ is not a principal ideal domain).

Are there examples where $O_L$ is not free over $O_K$? If yes: What is the *smallest* such example?

Or even better: Is there for every $K$ such an $L$?

Comment: I haven't worked out the details, but I remember that there are (many) examples of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m},\sqrt{n}) / \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{mn})$. The 1970 paper by Williams (see http://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/033.pdf) gives you explicit integral bases for the biquadratic fields over $\mathbb{Q}$ so that should save you from the biggest mess.

Comment: @SofieVerbeek: In Theorem 3 about the discriminant, didn't the author miss the cases $(n,m)\equiv (2,2)$ and $(n,m)\equiv (1,3)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One standard example is the number field $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-14})$ with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K=\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-14}]$, which is not a PID. Then the extension of number fields $L/K$ with $L=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-14},\sqrt{-7})$ has the property that
$\mathcal{O}_L$ is not free over $\mathcal{O}_K$.

Reference: The book "Number Theory" by Narkewicz. He shows that whenever $\mathcal{O}_K$ is not a PID there exists a quadratic
extension $L/K$ such that $\mathcal{O}_L$ is not free as an $\mathcal{O}_K$-module.

Comment: Thanks. Is it easy to see that $\mathcal O_L$ is not free over $\mathcal O_K$?

Comment: It is easy to find it in the literature, see Williams paper and its references, but not so easy, I suppose, to prove it yourself.

Comment: Great, thank you very much!